# Identify all possible parents and children across lists

Tags: r, xml, list, tree, nested-lists

I have 80,000 XML files that supposedly use the same format. However, this is clearly not the case. Because of this, I am attempting to identify all exisiting nodes and children in the files.

I have imported the XML-files as lists, using the XML package, and in the following I have described my input and my desired output.

Input (lists of lists):

```
XML1 <- list(name = "Company Number 1", 
             adress = list(street = "JP Street", number = "12"), 
             product = "chicken")

XML2 <- list(name = "Company Number 2", 
             company_adress = list(street = "House Street", number = "93"), 
             invoice = list(quantity = "2", product = "phone"))

XML3 <- list(company_name = "Company Number 3", 
             adress = list(street = "Lake Street", number = "1"), 
             invoice = list(quantity = "2", product = "phone", list(note = "Phones are refurbished")))
```

Output (tree structure across files with counts of occurrences at leafs):

```
List of 5
 $ name          : num 2
 $ company_name  : num 1
 $ adress        :List of 2
  ..$ street: num 2
  ..$ number: num 2
 $ company_adress:List of 2
  ..$ street: num 1
  ..$ number: num 1
 $ invoice       :List of 3
  ..$ quantity: num 2
  ..$ product : num 2
  ..$         :List of 1
  .. ..$ note: num 1
$ product        : num 1
```

Is there a package that can do something along this line, or do I need to write a function that does this myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have programmed a recursive loop that solves the problem. It is not elegant, but it does the trick.

The function takes a nested list and an empty vector.

```
# Summary tree for storing results
summary_tree <- list()

# Function
tree_merger <- function(tree, position) {
  # Testing if at the leaf of a tree
  if (is.character(tree) | is.null(tree)) {
    print("DONE")
  } else {
    # Position in tree
    if (length(position) == 0) {
      # Names of nodes
      tree_names <- names(tree)

      # Adding one to each name
      for (i in 1:length(tree_names)) {
        if (is.null(summary_tree[[tree_names[i]]])) {
          summary_tree[[tree_names[i]]] <<- list(1)
        } else {
          summary_tree[[tree_names[i]]] <<- list(summary_tree[[tree_names[i]]][[1]] + 1)
        }

        # Running function on new tree
        tree_merger(tree[[tree_names[i]]], c(position, tree_names[i]))
      }
    } else {
      # Names of nodes
      tree_names <- names(tree)

      # Finding position in tree to save information
      position_string <- NULL
      for (p in position) {
        position_string <- paste(position_string, "[[\"", p, "\"]]", sep = "")
      }
      position_string <- paste("summary_tree", position_string, sep = "")

      # Adding one to each position
      for (i in 1:length(tree_names)) {
        position_string_full <<- paste(position_string, "[[\"", tree_names[i], "\"]]", sep = "")

        # Adding to position
        if(is.null(eval(parse(text=position_string_full)))) {
         eval(parse(text=paste(position_string_full, "<<- list(1)")))
        } else {
          eval(parse(text=paste(position_string_full, "<<- list(", position_string_full ,"[[1]] + 1)")))
        }

        # Running function on new tree
        tree_merger(tree[[tree_names[i]]], c(position, tree_names[i]))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If anyone should run into the same problem, it should be noted that the code regarding how you exit the recursion should be probably be changed. For my XML files all "leafs" end either with a string or NULL. In other lists of lists it could be other types of values.